# Probabilities of related events

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I can't figure out which rules of probability to apply to solve for my probability of the second event.
My information for the question is as follows:

$P(A) = 0.3,
P(A \cap B) = 0.1$,
$P(A\cup B) \setminus (A \cap B) = 0.75$

I need to find the probability of B. Any guidance is appreciated

Comment: Have you made a Venn-diagram?

Comment: Suggestion: Fill in the given information into a Venn diagram.

Comment: Hint: $P((A\cup B) \backslash (A\cap B))=P(A\cap B^c)+P(A^c\cap B)$. This is useful if you use a two-way table.

Answer (score 0):

You have been given $\mathsf P(A), \mathsf P(A\cap B),$ and $\mathsf P((A\cup B)\smallsetminus(A\cap B))$, and wish to evaluate $\mathsf P(B)$ .

Well you can express some of these events as *unions of the disjoint events*: $(A\cap B), (A\smallsetminus B), (B\smallsetminus A)$.
$$\begin{align}A&=(A\cap B)\cup(A\smallsetminus B)\\B &= (A\cap B)\cup(B\smallsetminus A)\\(A\cup B)\smallsetminus(A\cap B)&=(A\smallsetminus B)\cup(B\smallsetminus A)\end{align}$$

So applying the additive rule :

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A)&=\mathsf P(A\cap B)+\mathsf P(A\smallsetminus B)\\\mathsf P(B)&=\mathsf P(A\cap B)+\mathsf P(B\smallsetminus A)\\\mathsf P((A\cup B)\smallsetminus(A\cap B))&=\mathsf P(A\smallsetminus B)+\mathsf P(B\smallsetminus A)\end{align}$$